# EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) Data Modeling/ Custom Database Fields

Tags: php, symfony4, entity-attribute-value

I would like to create custom fields User Registration, Login & Profile Management system.

I've multiple Clients. Each Client want to use different fields in the Registration form
 & these fields choice is fully up to Client's, this behaviour will same for the Profile or Login Page.

I've been searching since yesterday for the Library or Bundle which can perform these operations.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can think of is to create an "abstract" entity which will sum up all fields required for a given client.

```
/**
** @ORM\Entity() 
*/
class RegistrationFormField {
    // ...
    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") **/
    private $fieldName;
    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") **/
    private $fieldType;
    /** @ORM\Column(type="boolean") **/
    private $required;
    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Client") **/
    private $client;
    // ...
}
```

I would create this entity with all required fields so that I am able to build the corresponding registration form :

```
$fields = $em->getRepository(RegistrationFormField::class)->findBy(['client' => $client]);
$form = $this->createFormBuilder();
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    $form->add($field->getFieldName(), $field->getFieldType(), [
        'required' => $field->getRequired()
    ]);
}
```